# Making an app that executes an amount after an amount of time

Tags: php, jquery, automation, server-side

**Question**

Using PHP & Jquery how would you execute code after a given amount of time, say 1 month (even after the user has closed the browser etc)

**Scenario**

I've wanted to build an application that does something in an amount of time specified by the user, "sort of like hootsuite". But i cant get my head around how it would work.

I know you can use node.js (I struggle to understand and implement this in any of my laravel projects...) but even then wouldnt the server be filled with stress if say 1000 people had something waiting to be executed on the server for a whole month or even a year while still handling other user requests?

I've looked around a bit and CRON jobs came up but this doesnt sound like what i was looking for! Im not sure, ill be grateful if anyone can explain to me how they think i could go about it

Comment: Please clarify your question? why is not CRON suitable? what do you mean with "that does something"? And jQuery is not the way...

Comment: If your users are scheduling stuff in a month's time, then scheduling granularity could be coarse - say every 5 minutes. So maybe put the requests in a `sqlite` database, with a `time to run at` field and have a sever read it every 5 minutes and execute jobs. It can survive reboots and be backed up and could potentially be rehosted to a new server in case of server *"death"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell How would the server read the `time to run at` field? would this be using php or some other language?

Comment: It'd be SQL, which you can call from PHP, just something like `SELECT * FROM TABLE tasks WHERE TimeToRun < next5minutes` https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you're looking for is a *scheduling system*. The reason why the UNIX cron tool has come up in your searches is because it is a scheduling tool; it allows UNIX users to schedule tasks to happen at certain times. Other operating systems also have task schedulers.

#### Schedulers

The principal implementation strategy for a scheduler is some kind of polling mechanism, i.e., a software component which periodically checks to see if there are any scheduled tasks which are now due to be executed and, if so, executes them.

#### Implementation strategies

In order to implement something like this you would need a way to store information about scheduled tasks (e.g. when they're supposed to happen, who they belong to, what they're supposed to do). For example, you might use a database management system, or a file on disk.

You would also need a component to do the polling. This could be a daemon process (i.e. a process which is always running in the background) which includes a sleep (or wait or timeout) call which allows it to check at intervals for scheduled tasks, rather than constantly checking (and thereby most likely consuming all the CPU cycles!). Or it could be a program (in PHP if you like) which is itself run by cron on the host system, say, every five minutes which checks for scheduled tasks and then executes in, perhaps in separate processes. If you were to use cron, there are numerous PHP wrappers to help such as https://packagist.org/packages/peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler.

#### Services

However, instead of implementing all this yourself, you may consider making use of an existing service. There seem to be several options, including at least one free (within limits) service: https://atrigger.com/.